# how to input the variables LSTM model for tflite (C++)

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am studying "TFLITE" to implement ML on my device.
I am facing the problem that inputs for TFLITE model.
In python code, it is shown that LSTM input shape is 10, 1
But How am I suppose to input on C++ code into TFLITE model?
Every I googled result is 1, 1 input_shape is explained as example.
Thanks for your reply in advance.

-------Python Code to implement ML model-------
.....

```
model_x = Sequential()
model_x.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(10,1)))
model_x.add(Dense(1))
model_x.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model_x.summary()
```

-------C++Code to implement TFLITE model-------

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile("model_x.tflite");
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(model != nullptr);
    
    // Build the interpreter with the InterpreterBuilder.
    // Note: all Interpreters should be built with the InterpreterBuilder,
    // which allocates memory for the Interpreter and does various set up
    // tasks so that the Interpreter can read the provided model.
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    builder(&interpreter);
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter != nullptr);

    // Allocate tensor buffers.
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->AllocateTensors() == kTfLiteOk);

    // Fill input buffers
    // TODO(user): Insert code to fill input tensors.
    // Note: The buffer of the input tensor with index `i` of type T can
    // be accessed with `T* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<T>(i);`
    interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[0] = 0.503892;

    // vector<float> inputs = {    0.503892, 0.50349951,
    //                             0.50574788, 0.50799569,
    //                             0.49414472, 0.49407101,
    //                             0.50661932, 0.49726027,
    //                             0.50289517, 0.48882814 };
        
    const vector<int>& t_inputs = interpreter->inputs();
    TfLiteTensor* tensor = interpreter->tensor(t_inputs[0]);

    int input_size = tensor->dims->size;
    int batch_size = tensor->dims->data[0];
    int h = tensor->dims->data[1];
    int w = tensor->dims->data[2];
    int channels = tensor->dims->data[3];

    fprintf(stderr, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
        input_size, batch_size, h, w, channels);  // result 3, 1, 10, 1, 0

    // Run inference
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->Invoke() == kTfLiteOk);
    // printf("\n\n=== Post-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
    // tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());

    // Read output buffers
    // TODO(user): Insert getting data out code.
    // Note: The buffer of the output tensor with index `i` of type T can
    // be accessed with `T* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<T>(i);`
    float* result = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);
    fprintf(stderr, "predict : %f\n", *result);

    return 0;
}
```